# LINQ OrderBy with multiple layers

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class TestParent
{
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<TestGroup> GroupItems { get; set; }
}

public class TestGroup
{
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

How can I sort an object of type TestParent by ParentID and all the TestGroups in it by GroupID?

I could do it with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ResponseArray.Count; i++ )
{
    ResponseArray[i].GroupItems = ResponseArray[i].GroupItems
                                                  .OrderBy(x => x.GroupID)
                                                  .ToList();
}
return ResponseArray.OrderBy(x => x.GroupID).ToList();
```

It is possible to archieve the same using only LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` after the OrderBy and order the GroupItems inside that:

```
ResponseArray.OrderBy(t => t.ParentID).Select(t => new TestParent()
    { 
        ParentID = t.ParentID,
        GroupItems = t.GroupItems.OrderBy(g => g.GroupID).ToList() 
    })
```